# Mouseenter event only firing once for d3.js svg circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to create multiple circles when double clicking the canvas, and then doStuff() upon entering and leaving one of the circles.

Here is a jsfiddle with what I currently have set up: https://fiddle.jshell.net/r3ar8rc7/

However, when creating the circle, the mouseenter and mouseleave events are immediately fired, and then never happen again. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the functions straight away. Change your code to this:

```
.on('click', onClickCircle)
.on('mouseenter', onMouseEnterCircle)
.on('mouseleave', onMouseLeaveCircle)
```